# On full page load, detect if is Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In my app, I need to on full load, detect if is Electron, then fire a custom event. How to achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set electron UserAgent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672602/how-to-set-electron-useragent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(process.versions.electron != 'undefined' && process.versions.electron != null){
    //Custom event
}
```

I think is the most standard way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you! Can I introduce it inside a onload event?

Comment: @Plasmmer absolutely. This can be put just about anywhere,

Comment: How can I insert a else in this event?

Comment: @Plasmmer `if(process.versions.electron != 'undefined' && process.versions.electron != null){
    //Custom event
} else{//Do this if not electron}`

Answer (score 9):

I prefer this

```
// check if app is running inside the electron env or browser
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (userAgent.indexOf(' electron/') == -1) {
  // its not electron
}
```