# Verification with the new Google rest apis requirements (15.01.2019)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-oauth

in the requirements for using the Gmail REST APIs: https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy#additional-requirements-for-specific-api-scopes
There is the statement:

> Do not mislead Google about an application's operating environment. You must accurately represent the environment in which the authentication page appears. For example, don't claim to be an Android application in the user agent header if your application is running on iOS, or represent that your application's authentication page is rendered in a desktop browser if instead the authentication page is rendered in an embedded web view.

We have an Electron version of our app, that is only wrapping the web version URL in a desktop app. So we are using the OAuth flow for Web Server applications for both the web app and the desktop app. Can this be considered a valuation of the User Data Policy?

Comment: You can follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview), it is a guide on how to implement markup in your emails. But in order for you send a markup to your users,  you need to register it to them as stated in [Register with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `agent header`. This corresponds with the HTTP header `User-Agent`.

What Google is asking is that you use a User-Agent string that matches the platform that you are running on (android, iOS, Windows 10, ...). This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) will give you more information about `User-Agent`.

You can test what strings are included by your browser using this [site](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent). This should give you a better understanding. For example on my Windows 10 desktop using Chrome:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

This [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3) is the RFC7231 standard.

If your software is running in the browser, you don't need to do anything except don't override the `User-Agent` value. If you are writing your own custom software, then do some research and specify a `User-Agent` string that identifies the platform and append your software / company name.

Electron [publishes](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/electron-application/) a list of its User-Agent strings. My initial recommendation is just leave the User-Agent header alone and let Electron manage this for you.

This StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672988/8016720) shows how to set the Electron `User-Agent` header if you choose to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and detailed reply!